MenuItem Command not executing when defined through a style inside a ContextMenu
I am trying to create a file tree using a TreeView where I can bind a collection to. In order to bind to a TreeView you need to use a HierarchicalDataTemplate. This automatically uses the default TreeViewItem as its base. But I have no direct access to this TreeViewItem to add stuff to. This is why I am accessing the properties of this TreeViewItem using a style and setters.
Now when I add a ContextMenu through this style, all the commands and events that are assigned to the MenuItems won't fire. The ContextMenu still shows up fine when I right click the MenuItem.
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding FileTree}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu Width="250">
                        <!-- This command never gets executed when the menu item is clicked -->
                        <MenuItem Header="New File" Command="{Binding NewFile}" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:FileTreeModel}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding FileName, Converter={StaticResource FileNameToIconConverter}}"
                        Width="14" Height="12" Margin="5,0,5,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                        Stretch="Fill" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FileName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>

public class FileTreeModel
{
    public string? FileName { get; set; }
    public string? Path { get; set; }
    public IList<FileTreeModel> Children { get; set; } = [];
}

public ObservableCollection<FileTreeModel> FileTree { get; }
public ICommand NewFile { get; }

public ExplorerViewModel(INewFileService newFileService)
{
    FileTree = [];
    NewFile = new RelayCommand(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New file"); // Never gets ran
        newFileService.NewFile();
    });
}



You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the class and the NewFile property, this way the UI gets an update that the property has changed. (I guess the UI loads the property before you can init it.)

@k1ll3r8e This is already a large project, I have a ViewModel class that implements all of the required things which each viewmodel class inherrits from.

NewFile belongs as a property to the ExplorerViewModel. But your TreeviewItems bind each to a FileTreeModel. So the binding to NewFile command won't resolve. Check the output window in VS at truntime. It will likely report a System.Data error that reports exactly this unresolved binding.

@lidqy I use JetBrains Rider, which shows me where im binding from. It's telling me that its from ExplorerViewModel. I currently have a very hacky solution. I use .ItemContainerStyle instead of .Resources, which means its now looking for the command in FileTreeModel. I now added the command in there and it works. This is definitely not preferred, and I would still like a better solution.

Without knowing how you set the Data Context, it is impossible to give an exact answer to your question.
One of the possible variants:
<Window -------------------
        -------------------
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:FilesTreeViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>


    ----------------------------

                    <ContextMenu Width="250">
                        <!-- This command never gets executed when the menu item is clicked -->
                        <MenuItem Header="New File"
                                  Command="{Binding NewFile, Source={StaticResource vm}}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>


    ----------------------------


The solution I have found was changing TreeView.Resources to TreeView.ItemContainerStyle. This means it will now try to find the command inside the container model, instead of the view model. This is a very hacky solution, and I would still like to figure out a way that allows me to have the command inside the view model.
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding FileTree}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu Width="250">
                        <!-- It will now try to find the NewFile command inside FileTreeModel, because of ItemContainerStyle -->
                        <MenuItem Header="New File" Command="{Binding NewFile}" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:FileTreeModel}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding FileName, Converter={StaticResource FileNameToIconConverter}}"
                        Width="14" Height="12" Margin="5,0,5,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                        Stretch="Fill" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FileName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>

public class FileTreeModel
{
    public string? FileName { get; set; }
    public string? Path { get; set; }
    public IList<FileTreeModel> Children { get; set; } = [];

    public ICommand NewFileCommand { get; }

    public FileTreeModel()
    {
        NewFile = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New file");
        });
    }
}

